# Interpreting Python List Output

Tags: python

I am having a hard time understanding why the output of this Python code is 1. Just to add, I am just new to programming:

What is the output of the following snippet:

```
lst = [3, 1, -2]
print(lst[lst[-1]])
```

Comment: `lst[-1] == -2` then it becomes `lst[-2]` which is grabbing second last element from `lst`, i.e. `1`.

Comment: I think what might be confusing you is that [-0] is also valid, as in you count from 0 not 1. If you use positive numbers you count from the left side, and negatives count from the right side

Comment: Oh wow! It makes a lot of sense now! Hahaha thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris mentioned in comments, `lst[-1]` is equal to -2, so from `lst[lst[-1]]` becomes `lst[-2]`. This code picks the second item from back.

Actually, there are always two indices for one item in lists in Python. I hope this schema will help you to better understand:

```
 0  1   2
 ↓  ↓   ↓
[3, 1, -2]
 ↑  ↑   ↑
-3 -2  -1
```

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-basics-of-indexing-and-slicing-python-lists-2d12c90a94cf) you can find a The Basics of Indexing and Slicing Python Lists tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The negative indexing starts from where the array ends. This means that the last element of the array is the first element in the negative indexing which is -1.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print (arr[-1]) # output 5 
print (arr[-2])  #output 4
#arr[-3] =3
print(arr[arr[-3]]) #output 4
```

Comment: from my answer few parts with explanations have been deleted and message is appearing like this "deleted repetitive parts from question". I am apologizing for this